# How to add JAR to local Maven repo manually AND set JAR's dependicies?

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

It is told everywhere that to add some JAR to maven local repo manually is is required to issue a command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-2.3.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code -DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

This worked for me, but a jar was added to repo as is, i.e. without information about other jars it depends on.

How to describe dependicies also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but perhaps this documentation? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html

Comment: And what to write in this POM?

Comment: You should add in the pom all the dependencies you will need at runtime, to make use of your jar. When you declare a dependency to your jar in a child project, you will get the needed transitive dependencies. You need however to know which dependencies you need at compile time and runtime